# How do I write the CSS for flipping images with those images declared in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have written a program in javascript that matches the images which are randomly shuffled in a 4x4 grid. I have read that for flipping the images, you need to have a front image and a back image. I have declared the "back" images for my program in an Array inside of Javascript and have the common "front" image declared in the div holding those images. Now, I am unable to target the front or back images in my program for applying all the css3 transformation code as they are declared in the Javascript. Hence, I need help in suggesting me a way to achieve flipping in my program. Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"> 
        Match The Flag!
    </div>

    <div id="clicks"> </div>
    <div id="memory_board" onClick="Click()"></div>
    <script>newBoard();</script>
    <!-- <button onclick=" return newBoard();"> Reset </button> -->

    <div class="refresh">
        <img src="images/refresh.png" alt="refresh" onclick="return location.reload();">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javscript**

```
<script>
var memory_array = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() /* Shuffle Function to Randomly Position the Cards */
{
    var i = this.length, j, temp;   /* this.length keyword will automatically take the length of the parameter passed to the parent function i.e array of cards */
    while(i--){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = this[j];
        this[j] = this[i];
        this[i] = temp;
    }
}
function newBoard()
{
    var i = 0;
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    var output = '';
    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
        output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
    localStorage.setItem("score1", clicks);
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile, val)
{
    if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2)
    {
        tile.style.background = '#FFF';
        tile.innerHTML = '<img src="' + val + '.png"/>';    /* Adding .png format after our image array */
        if(memory_values.length == 0)   /* For First Click on the image */
        {
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        } 
        else if(memory_values.length == 1)  /* For Second Click on the other image */
        {
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
            console.log(memory_values[0]+" "+memory_values[1]);
            if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1])
            {
                document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]).style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
                document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]).style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
                tiles_flipped += 2;
                memory_values = []; /* Clear arrays */
                memory_tile_ids = []; /* Clear arrays */

                if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) /* Check to see if all cards are flipped back */
                {
                    var score = Click();
                    score--;
                    /*console.log("Score: "+score);/*
                    /*alert("All Tiles Flipped. Your Score: "+score);*/

                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    /*newBoard();*/ // Don't Remove
                    /*var i = 0;
                    location.reload();*/
                }
            } 
            else    /* If the images don't match, then flip the two flipped images back */ 
            {
                function flipBack() 
                {
                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                    tile_1.style.background = 'url(images/card.png) no-repeat';
                    tile_1.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%';

                    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                    tile_2.style.background = 'url(images/card.png) no-repeat';
                    tile_2.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%';
                    tile_2.innerHTML = "";

                    memory_values = [];     /* Clear arrays */
                    memory_tile_ids = [];   /* Clear arrays */
                }
                setTimeout(flipBack, 700);
            }
        }
    }
}
        var clicks = 0;
        var previous_scores = localStorage.getItem("old-score");
        console.log(previous_scores);
        function Click() 
        {
            if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length)
            {
                document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "New Score: "+clicks+"<br>"+"Old Score: "+previous_scores;
                localStorage.setItem("old-score", clicks);
                /*window.location.href = "score.html";*/

            }
            else
            {
                clicks += 1;
                document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "Clicks: "+clicks;
                return clicks;
            }
        }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#memory_board
{
    width: 760px;
    height: 660px;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#memory_board > div
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    background: url('images/card.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 130px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 64px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#tile_0 img, #tile_1 img, #tile_2 img, #tile_3 img, #tile_4 img, #tile_5 img, #tile_6 img, #tile_7 img, #tile_8 img, #tile_9 img, #tile_10 img, #tile_11 img, #tile_12 img, #tile_13 img, #tile_14 img, #tile_15 img
{
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of flipping an image from a front image to a back image.

You should be able to adapt this example so that it works within your setup.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/400/520') 0 0 / 100px 130px no-repeat;
}

.card .back {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/1600/2080') 0 0 / 100px 130px no-repeat;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**Credit:** The example above is modified from the markup and styling provided in the tutorial at:

https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html